# An act of making a citizen work (spy?) against his own country

Tags: word-request

What's the right word to describe an act of making a citizen of one country (by either paying him or, perhaps, setting him up in some way) start getting and sharing some important info about his own country?

For example,

> The FBI forces finally ______________(ed) the Russian scientist Ivanov
>   in 1957. So, starting from 1957 he's been sending all important
>   information about Russian militaries to the White House.

(or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conventional term is *turn*, but it does not imply compulsion, as your term "make" does; it may involve payment or principled persuasion as well as blackmail.

And just by the way: the FBI is a domestic agency; it may recruit Russians within the US but would not ordinarily run or recruit agents abroad. That's the job of the CIA.

> The CIA turned the Russian scientist Ivanov in 1957.

Comment: Turn, as used in the sentence doesn’t convey the meaning. Could be negative or positive. Turned Ivanov what?

Comment: @user070221 I suggest that within the context of espionage, **turn** means to cause to change sides regardless of negative or positive interpretations.

Comment: @RonaldSole - OP clearly refers to a negative, evil intent: “*making a citizen of one country (by either paying him or, perhaps, setting him up in some way)*”

Comment: @user070221 As Ronald Sole says, in this context simple transitive *turn* is quite common and means approximately "induce to change allegiance and provide information". Negative/positive is determined by which side you're on!

Comment: @StoneyB - I disagree, whatever side you are on,  we are   in any  case talking about corruption. One side may benefit, while the other side may lose..but it is not a positive in itself.

Comment: to turn someone is "spycraft" language for getting a person to change allegiances. It's everywhere in spy novels, movies, etc. There is absolutely no ambiguity here. "Turned Ivanov what?" is the wrong question. "The FBI turned Ivanov"=caused him to change his allegiances. The FBI works in the US to catch spies. And when they do, they can exert pressure. The CIA does not work on catching spies inside the US borders.....

Comment: I recently read [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/09/01/us/politics/deripaska-ohr-steele-fbi.html) which reminded me of the word *cultivate*. It's not the best word here (I don't know how exactly they persuaded Ivanov), but it's obviously used in this context and it might come in handy. @user070221 The OED contains the following (29. c.) definition of the verb *turn* (transitive): "To induce or persuade (a person) to act against his country, former associates, etc., esp. as a spy."

Comment: @userr2684291 - that’s an interesting definition, apparently not a common one. Not all users have access to the OED and learners in particular might find the entry helpful. I think it should be included in the post, for a more complete answer. Unluckily reference is not commonly cited on ELL. Having said that, what’s the difference between that definition of “turn” and that of “corrupt”?

Comment: @Lambie - can you please cite a source for the definition you find “everywhere in spy  novels” apart from the already cited OED?

Comment: @user070221 *Corrupt* is primarily, as you quote, about something dishonest or immoral, and, depending on the side you're on, may by extension refer to the same thing. *Turn* doesn't characterize the turned as such (dishonest, etc.) on its own (i.e. it's neutral and therefore appropriate in more unbiased (with respect to the subject at issue) discourse) and is meaning-wise a perfect fit in the given context.

Comment: Sense 27 in the [*Collins English Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn) is also pretty darn close to the one given in the OED: "to cause (an enemy agent) to become a double agent working for one's own side".

Comment: @userr2684291 - I have no qualms with this answer, but the definition you give is “to induce a person to act against his country” how can that be neutral?

Comment: @user070221 It's neutral because it doesn't characterize the act as either good or bad. What's considered an act against against a country (de jure) need not in fact be morally reprehensible.

Comment: @userr2684291 - well, that would be good for any criminal act. Anyway thanks for providing a dictionary entry with the relevant definition.